# Clojure: boot repl in a particular namespace

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

I have boot-clj installed and want to be able to edit a .clj file in an external editor and separately have a command line REPL running from which I can call the functions that I change in the .clj file. No special reloading commands should be required.

Another thing is I don't want to have to manually type commands to include namespaces - I would like to just run a script that brings me into the namespace, so I can call existing functions right away.

Name of the file:

```
C:\dev\my-project\src\my_project\utils.clj
```

Something of what is inside the file:

```
(ns my-project.utils
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as s]))

(defn my-range [start end]
  (take (- end start) (iterate inc start)))
```

I would like to go straight into a REPL and go `(my-range 0 3)` and see if it produces the result I want.

What's the setup for this? What would the script file I need to run look like?

My current understanding is that the answer will look something like this:

```
(deftask dev-repl
  (set-env! …)
  (repl))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### at the command line

You can achieve this to some degree at the command line, without creating a `build.boot` file:

*In C:\dev\my_project*:

```
boot -r src repl -n my-project.utils
```

- `boot -r src`: starts boot with `src` on the "resource paths", which is the set of directories that will be accessible within the JVM.
- `repl -n my-project.utils` starts a REPL, requires your namespace, and enters it.

While the REPL is running, and after you have edited `C:\dev\my_project\src\my_project\utils.clj`, you can reload it at the REPL like this:

```
my-project.utils=> (require 'my-project.utils :reload)
nil
```

### minimal `build.boot`

Alternatively, you could create the file `C:\dev\my_project\build.boot` with these contents:

```
(set-env! :resource-paths #{"src"})

(deftask dev 
  "Run a development REPL"
  []
  (repl :init-ns 'my-project.utils))
```

Then, in `C:\dev\my_project`:

```
boot dev
```

Which will also start a REPL in your namespace, but requires less command-line configuration as we've performed the configuration in `build.boot`, which `boot` will automatically evaluate.

> Note: from a Clojure REPL, regardless of build tool, you can require any namespace (as long as it's on the JVM's class path) with the `require` function and enter it with the `in-ns` function.

### build.boot with automatic reloading

Finally, it's possible to combine features of Boot to achieve a development workflow oriented around automatically reloading code.

*In `C:\dev\my_project\build.boot`*:

```
(set-env! :resource-paths #{"src"})

(require '[boot.core :as core]
         '[boot.pod  :as pod])

(deftask load-ns
  "Loads the my-project.utils namespace in a fresh pod."
  []
  (let [pods (pod/pod-pool (core/get-env))]
    (core/with-pre-wrap [fileset]
      (pod/with-eval-in (pods :refresh)
        ;; We require indirectly here so that errors from my-project.utils have
        ;; proper line and column information.
        (require 'my-project.load-impl))
      fileset)))

(deftask dev
  "Watches source code and loads my-project/utils every time code changes."
  []
  (comp (watch)
        (load-ns)))
```

*In `C:\dev\my_project\src\my_project\load_impl.clj`*:

```
(ns my-project.load-impl)

(require 'my-project.utils)
```

*In `C:\dev\my_project\src\my_project\utils.clj`*:

```
(ns my-project.utils
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as s]))

(defn my-range [start end]
  (take (- end start) (iterate inc start)))

(println "In the code!")
(println "(my-range 0 10) = " (my-range 10 20))
```

Back at the command prompt, type `boot dev`.  You should see some `println` output, and every time you edit and save the file you should see it again, reflecting any changes you made.

Comment: That's great thanks - will allow me to run code without restarting a new JVM every time. I wonder if the `(require ...)` can somehow be put first in the history so it is only a few up keystrokes away, or turned into a command like `r`??

Comment: You can type Ctrl-r at the REPL to search command history. You could also add a function to your namespace and call it from the REPL with (r): (defn r [] (require ...))

Comment: I like the `(r)` trick (even though it is a special reloading command). Interesting that if I change the name of a function the old function is still in the namespace.

Comment: I'm new to SO and am not sure if you were notified, but I made a major edit to my answer.  It now includes instructions for an auto-reloading setup I hope you'll enjoy.

Comment: Yes I saw that thanks, meant you answered the question perfectly. I'm sticking with the `(r)` trick for now as it basically does what I need and has less moving parts than the real answer.

Comment: For a disciplined approach when building software, you may want to adopt the reloaded workflow by Stuart Sierra. A boot task for automatic reloading is available at https://github.com/danielsz/system.