# Reloadable Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

How to create a REPL for Clojure for which the code is reloadable?

I can create a new project, and get a REPL up and running:

```
lein new app stack 
cd stack
lein repl
(-main)
```

Doing the above should get you "Hello, World!".

I would like to stay in the REPL, change the code to `println` "Howdy partner!", and then just `(-main)` again. Either auto-reloading or (perhaps even better) simple manual reloading (for instance with a command like `(r)`) would make the environment complete.

It seems with lein I'm already getting into the right namespace (any namespace but the user namespace from which you then have to `(in-ns 'some-ns)` is the right namespace!). The only unanswered part is code reloading - either manual or auto.

As it happens I previously asked how to do this with [boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982533/clojure-boot-repl-in-a-particular-namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the [lein-autoreload](https://github.com/pyronicide/lein-autoreload) plugin for automatic reloading.

Answer (score 2):

For manual reloading you can use the same trick as posted in the boot answer, which is to have a function that does the reloading for you:

```
(defn r [] (require 'stack.core :reload))
```

Once the above function is part of the `stack.core` namespace, you can call it from the REPL. Pretty simple - the namespace `stack.core` has a function in it which reloads itself.

Make code changes from the editor, reload with `(r)`, then run again...